# how can i be certain the json file syntax is correct

Tags: json, validation

Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

This was the output of the json file which was generated by twint (the opensource twitter **scraping** tool). But i cannot validate the json file with a proper json validator. What can I do?
The json sample file is blow

```
 {
    "id": 672640248707436544,
    "conversation_id": "672640248707436544",
    "created_at": 1449204907000,
    "date": "2015-12-04",
    "time": "07:55:07",
    "timezone": "EAT",
    "user_id": 25073877,
    "username": "realdonaldtrump",
    "name": "Donald J. Trump",
    "place": "",
    "tweet": "\"@Kacee50: @realDonaldTrump We can't take 8 years of Hilary or 8 years of establishment GOP!!! We need Trump!!\"",
    "mentions": ["kacee50", "realdonaldtrump"],
    "urls": [],
    "photos": [],
    "replies_count": 252,
    "retweets_count": 980,
    "likes_count": 2787,
    "hashtags": [],
    "cashtags": [],
    "link": "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/672640248707436544",
    "retweet": false,
    "quote_url": "",
    "video": 0,
    "near": "",
    "geo": "",
    "source": "",
    "user_rt_id": "",
    "user_rt": "",
    "retweet_id": "",
    "reply_to": [{
        "user_id": "25073877",
        "username": "realDonaldTrump"
    }, {
        "user_id": "3294546230",
        "username": "Kacee50"
    }],
    "retweet_date": "",
    "translate": "",
    "trans_src": "",
    "trans_dest": ""
} {.... the error is in here...
```

Comment: Hey, would have been great for readers if you could format your JSON as code and some formatting. 

Putting your JSOn payload in something like www.jsonlint.com shows its valid json, hard to actually help answer your question here. Do you have a few more details?

Answer (score 0):

you can use online JSON parsers to help you find errors in your json, and even repairing common errors.
here is one example [jsoneditoronline](https://jsoneditoronline.org/), find more tools on search engines